# Unable to get visible/live Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am stuck in this problem.

I want to maintain **live instance of Fragment** in application context. What I did is

## 1st Attempt

```
public class BaseProjectFragmentParent extends BaseProjectFragment {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        App.getInstance().setLiveFragment(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        App.getInstance().setLiveFragment(null);
    }
}
```

and I extend all fragments by this base class. I expected live instance to be there in Application class.

**Problem** is in `ViewPager`, I have two `Fragment` in `ViewPager` where both Fragment's `onResume()` is called and live instance is set the second Fragment. I am working on some common code so I don't want to use `getCurrentItem()`.

## Second Attempt

Next I tried to get this Live Fragment by **`getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()`**

1. `isVisible()` is **`true`** for both Fragments. (Not useful)
2. `isResumed()` is **`true`** for both Fragments. (Not useful)

Comment: Is `mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` can help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)
```

In fragments. This flag is set by the OS when a fragment becomes visible:

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyFragment() {
        setUserVisibleHint(false) //This is needed because by default its true 
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
         super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
         //true if fragment is visible
    }
}
```

However this wont get called inside Viewpager. You have to add a listener to the viewpager and then set your active page manually:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // Check if this is the page you want.
}
});
```